# Why is None getting printed, even if the return value isn't None (It happens only for the else condition)

Tags: python

```
def armstrong(x):
    number = str(x)
    length = len(number)
    sum=0
    for i in number:
        sum = sum + pow(int(i),length)

    print("Yes {0} is an Armstrong Number" .format(x) if(sum==x) else print("No {0} is not an Armstrong Number" .format(x)))   

    return 0


num=int(input("Enter a Number: "))
armstrong(num)
```

> For a non armstrong number the output comes along with a None, could someone please explain the reason behind it. I've attached the output as an image link for the same.

[image: log]

Comment: Remove the `print()` from the `else` and just have the string be the else-value in the `if ... else` operator. In any event -- why not make `armstrong()` return a Boolean values and let the calling code be responsible for printing? That would be a more useful function and a cleaner design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `print` within another `print`, and since `print` always returns `None`, that's what you're printing. I'm guessing this is what you need:

```
print("Yes {0} is an Armstrong Number".format(x) if(sum==x) else "No {0} is not an Armstrong Number".format(x))
```

P.S try not to use the word `sum` because you're shadowing a built-in function